# Equivalent of C# InvokeMapType in Java?

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am currently converting a C# Xamarin project but cannot find the equivalent of the following in Java for Android?

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
                .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeSatellite)
                .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(false)
                .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nearly the same.

```
GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
    .mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)
    .zoomControlsEnabled(false)
    .compassEnabled(true);
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions) lists all the options you have.